# Avoid Circular Dependency injection

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

In my Angular application, I am implementing 2 services:

- AuthenticationService
- IdleService

These two services depend on each other:

1. When I logout I have to stop watching the user idleness (by calling a method in the `IdleService`)
2. When the user is timed out, I have to call a `logout` method from the `AuthenticationService` to log out the user.

This approach is causing a circular dependency problem. Do you have any idea how to avoid it or how to change my actual approach by a better one?

Comment: maybe use mediator pattern to handle service to service communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the auth service is responsible holding, managing, and exposing the state of user authentication. By this I am saying the auth service should not care about user idleness at all. This is the responsibility of the idle service.

So I would create a BehaviorSubject in the auth service that broadcasts the state of the user authentication. The idle service can use the subject to determine when an idle timer needs to start/stop.

```
export class AuthService {
    user: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    logIn(){
        // logic to log user in
        this.user.next(true);
    }
    logOut(){
        // logic to log user out
        this.user.next(false);
    }
}
```

Now the idle service can inject the auth service and determine how to handle the idle timer

```
export class IdleService {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService){
        this.authService.user.subscribe(res => {
            // watch user authentication state and determine how to handle idle timer
        });
    }

    idleOut(){
        this.authService.logOut();
    }
}
```

For this to work you will have to inject the IdleService on app load (for example in the app.component so the IdleService constructor method runs. I am not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but this is the first thing that comes to mind. Here is a very basic [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdno6w?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) demoing this concept.

Answer (score 2):

In the book [Dependency Injection in .NET 2nd edition](https://manning.com/seemann2/) (§6.3), Mark Seemann and I describe that Dependency cycles are often caused by [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) violations. My impression is that this is the case as well in your specific situation. SRP is typically violated when a class has many methods that are not very cohesive.

The solution is to split up either one of the two classes `AuthenticationService` and `IdleService` (or perhaps even both) into smaller classes.

Comment: I think that SRP is reflected in LLai's solution where he took off the idleness management from the Authentication service and keep it only in the Idleness service. Otherwise, `AuthenticationService` has only methods that deal with authentication (`login` and `logout`), and `IdleService` has only idleness methods that watch for user idleness, trigger the timeout...Perhaps I am not seeing things clearly but I can't think about how I can split each one of these services into smaller classes

Comment: LLai's solution deals with SRP as well, although he didn't mention this explicitly. I can't really comment on how exactly to fix the SRP violation, since you didn't include any code. But separating methods id just one way of combatting SRP, but will not always solve the problem, since even a single-method class can still violate SRP.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an observable or a subject in `IdleService` which returns a disconnect message if the times goes out. This way, only `AuthenticationService` imports `IdleService`. For example:

```
import { IdleService } from './services/idle.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; 

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  disconnect: Obervable<boolean>;

  constructor(private idleService: IdleService) { 
    this.disconnect = this.idleService.disconnectObservable;
    this.disconnect.subscribe(res => {
      if (res === true) {
        this.logout();
      }
    });
  }

  logout() {
  //some code here
  }
}
```

In the `IdleService`:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class IdleService {

  public disconnectObservable: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor() {
    this.disconnectObservable = new Observable(observer => {
      // insert your logic here
      setTimeout(() => {
          observer.next('true');
      }, 1000);

      setTimeout(() => {
          observer.complete();
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
}
```